# A simple while-loop in GCC inline assembly

Tags: c++, gcc, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

I want to write the following loop using GCC extended inline ASM:

```
long* arr = new long[ARR_LEN]();
long* act_ptr = arr;
long* end_ptr = arr + ARR_LEN;

while (act_ptr < end_ptr)
{
    *act_ptr = SOME_VALUE;
    act_ptr += STEP_SIZE;
}

delete[] arr;
```

An array of type `long` with length `ARR_LEN` is allocated and zero-initialized. The loop walks through the array with an increment of `STEP_SIZE`. Every touched element is set to `SOME_VALUE`.

Well, this was my first attempt in GAS:

```
long* arr = new long[ARR_LEN]();

asm volatile
(
    "loop:"
    "movl %[sval], (%[aptr]);"
    "leal (%[aptr], %[incr], 4), %[aptr];"
    "cmpl %[eptr], %[aptr];"
    "jl loop;"
    : // no output
    : [aptr] "r" (arr),
      [eptr] "r" (arr + ARR_LEN),
      [incr] "r" (STEP_SIZE),
      [sval] "i" (SOME_VALUE)
    : "cc", "memory"
);

delete[] arr;
```

As mentioned in the comments, it is true that this assembler code is more of a `do {...} while` loop, but it does in fact do the same work.

The strange thing about that piece of code really is, that it worked fine for me at first. But when I later tried to make it work in another project, it just seemed as if it wouldn't do anything. I even made some 1:1 copies of the *working* project, compiled again and... still the result is random.

Maybe I took the wrong constraints for the input operands, but I've actually tried nearly all of them by now and I have no real idea left. What puzzles me in particular is, that it still works in some cases.

I am not an expert at ASM whatsoever, although I learned it when I was still at university. Please note that I am not looking for optimization - I am just trying to understand how inline assembly works. So here is my question: Is there anything fundamentally wrong with my attempt or did I make a more subtle mistake here? Thanks in advance.

(Working with g++ MinGW Win32 x86 v.4.8.1)

**Update**

I have already tried out every single suggestion that has been contributed here so far. In particular I tried

- using the "q" operand constraint instead of "r", sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't,
- writing `... : [aptr] "=r" (arr) : "0" (arr) ...` instead, same result,
- or even `... : [aptr] "+r" (arr) : ...`, still the same.

Meanwhile I know the official [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm) pretty much by heart, but I still can't see my error.

Comment: `act_ptr += STEP_SIZE;` could STEP_SZIE evalve pointer arythmetic that leaves the bounds? Even if its without derefferencing?

Comment: Have you tried a gdb debugging session already?

Comment: In the C++ loop, the loop-condition is checked before executing the loop-body, but in the assembler version you check it after the body (in other words, your assembler code is more of a `do ... while (...)` loop). This means that you can (and probably do) write out of bounds of the allocated memory.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think you're right in general, but in this case it should work fine as long as I use `jl` instead of `jle` for looping.

Comment: You are not, by any chance, compiling as 64-bit in your new project?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I wish I were...

Comment: In that case, it's time to break out the debugger...

Comment: `;`  isn't for comments? did you tried `\n`?

Comment: @Alex According to the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) You can separate multiple instructions by the characters normally used in assembly code for the system. A combination that works in most places is `\n\t`. Also `;` works, if the assembler allows semicolons as a line-breaking character.

Comment: My wrong, I just opened the `-S` `.S` output with `vim` and it shown the code after `;` as commented, but a diff of two `objdump -S` with `;` and `\n` show no differences, so you're right. I get a `free()` error executing the code (as if the aptr become invalid), maybe is needed to clobber the used registers?

Comment: @Alex Hmm, I'm gonna have a look on this, thank. I thought choosing the `"r"` constraint for an operand instead of specifying a particular register obviates the need for it to be on the clobber list.

Comment: The first `movl` work but when I enable the `leal` it fail.

Comment: I changed the `lea` instruction to an `add` variant, but the result is the same.

Comment: @MatsPetersson debugging brought no further insights. Everything seems to work as it is supposed to, but the array still contains no data...

Comment: Work for me if I use `"q"` (`a b c d` registers) instead of `"r"`, by default `esi` was used. Notice that the C version assembled is different from your implmentation, buf if I try asm inline it again `esi` is chosen and fail.

Comment: @Alex works for me too. But I don't see why that makes a difference in this case. Every instruction that I use should take general register operands...

Comment: In my case `esi` is the register where the return of `new` is stored and never updated and this is why the `delete` then fail. Guess is better to explicit the registers to use and clobber them.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying an input operand (`aptr`) which is not allowed. Either constrain it match an output operand or change it to an input/output operand.

Comment: Sounds plausible, but the result stays the same... thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete code that has the intended behavior.

- Note that the code is written for a 64-bit machine. Therefore, for example `%%rbx` is used instead of `%%ebx` as the base address for the array. For the same reason `leaq` and `cmpq` should be used instead of `leal` and `cmpl`.
- `movq` should be used since the array is of type `long`.
- Type `long` is 8 byte not 4 byte on a 64-bit machine.
- `jl` in the question should be changed to `jg`.
- Register labels can not be used since they will be replaced by the compiler with the 32-bit version of the chosen register (e.g., `ebx`).
- Constraint `"r"` can not be used. `"r"` means any register can be used, however not any combination of registers is acceptable for `leaq`. Look here: [x86 addressing modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes)

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  int main(){

    int ARR_LEN=20;
    int STEP_SIZE=2;
    long SOME_VALUE=100;

    long* arr = new long[ARR_LEN];

    int i;


    for (i=0; i<ARR_LEN; i++){
      arr[i] = 0;
    }

    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
      "loop:"
      "movq %%rdx, (%%rbx);"
      "leaq (%%rbx, %%rcx, 8), %%rbx;"
      "cmpq %%rbx, %%rax;"
      "jg loop;"
      : // no output
      : "b" (arr),
        "a" (arr+ARR_LEN),
        "c" (STEP_SIZE),
        "d" (SOME_VALUE)
      : "cc", "memory"
    );

    for (i=0; i<ARR_LEN; i++){
      cout << "element " << i << " is " << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] arr;

    return 0;

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

How about an answer that works for both x86 and x64 (although it does assume longs are always 4 bytes, a la Windows)?  The main change from the OP is using "+r" and (temp).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  int ARR_LEN=20;
  size_t STEP_SIZE=2;
  long SOME_VALUE=100;

  long* arr = new long[ARR_LEN];

  for (int i=0; i<ARR_LEN; i++){
    arr[i] = 0;
  }

  long* temp = arr;

   asm volatile (
      "loop:\n\t"
      "movl %[sval], (%[aptr])\n\t"
      "lea (%[aptr], %[incr], %c[size]), %[aptr]\n\t"
      "cmp %[eptr], %[aptr]\n\t"
      "jl loop\n\t"
      : [aptr] "+r" (temp)
      : [eptr] "r" (arr + ARR_LEN),
        [incr] "r" (STEP_SIZE),
        [sval] "i" (SOME_VALUE),
        [size] "i" (sizeof(long))
      : "cc", "memory"
   );

  for (int i=0; i<ARR_LEN; i++){
    cout << "element " << i << " is " << arr[i] << endl;
  }

  delete[] arr;

  return 0;
}
```